# Setting Chrome extension options for a Google Apps Organization

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension that takes options, per https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options.  For my extension I need to give Google Apps administrators the ability to set and enforce the options at the Google Apps Organization level and disable users from modifying them.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this?  I'm not finding any help in the documentation or in searching online.

Thanks.
Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly how to work with it, but you can use [`storage.managed` storageArea](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/storage) that is read-only and can (apparently) be populated from Google Apps policies for signed-in users.

More information on `chrome.storage`: [API docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).